# Create python class constructor like imaginary number (a + bj)

Tags: python, class, oop

Is there any way to initialise a class in python with a letter after a number? When initialising an imaginary number in Python, we can do `a + bj`, where `a` is the real part and `b` is the imaginary part.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this kind of initialisation for a custom class. For example, I am defining a class of [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number), and I was looking for a way to initialise my class as `a + bd`, where `a` is the real part and `b` is the dual part.

Comment: Why not ? You'l just need to handle it properly and remove the letter

Comment: No.  The `j` is special syntax that specifies an imaginary number.  There is no general suffix ability.  You can do this in C++ now, however.

Comment: @azro No, you can't make Python accept `x = 3+4d`.

Comment: @TimRoberts `for a custom class`. If you create your class, you pass it whatever you want

Comment: @azro  No, you can't.  The Python parser won't accept it.  I suspect you are thinking about passing a string `"3+4d"`.  That's not what he's asking.

Comment: No, you cannot define custom literals without hacking the runtime itself somehow

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take an approach where you have to implement the basic operations yourself. Instead of writing `a1 = a + bε` you create a class `a1 = MyDualNumbers(a=1, b=2)`.

```py
class MyDualNumbers:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        """ Where we have a + bε"""
        self.a = a # real number a
        self.b = b # real number b
        
    def __add__(self, other):
        # implement addition of DualNumber
        pass
        
    def __sub__(self, other):
        pass
        
    def __mul__(self, other):
        pass
    
a1 = MyDualNumber(1,2)
a2 = MyDualNumber(3,4)

a3 = a1 + a2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Molitoris. I have already defined my class, I am looking for a way to modify the constructor as in your example `a1 = a + bε `.

Comment: I am not sure how easy this is to implement. However, the concept with the class also exists for complex numbers (see [here](https://www.askpython.com/python/python-complex-numbers))

Comment: It is IMPOSSIBLE to implement.  It CANNOT be done.  Python has exactly one numeric suffix: the `j`.  That's all there is.  End of story.